# curl graphql file in the middle of string

Tags: curl, graphql

Hej Guys!

I apologise if this question is irrelevant but I have spent the last two days trying to figure this out and I feel I hit a roadblock, so I decided to ask for help. I am trying to send a curl request to a graphQl but hit a road block and don't know how to get out of it.

so basically this is my curl request:

```
curl \
-X POST \
-H "Content-Type: application/json"  \
--data '{"query":"mutation{sayHello(data:\"text\")}"}' \
http://localhost:3306/
```

Now, the thing is, the "text" is actually a variable and I wanted to include a text file on it, but get always error. This was my attempt:

```
curl \
-X POST \
-H "Content-Type: application/json"  \
--data '{"query":"mutation{sayHello(data:@text.txt)}"}' \
http://localhost:3306/
```

also tried to add variables to the query string but without any success. Any tips?

Comment: of course variables should be used (how 'tried'?) ... after some reads @ can't insert file content in the middle [of string], only end/attach ... you have to use some external tool to inject/convert/create query (template?) .... are you injecting files into SQL DB the same way? sometimes 'tools' are required

Comment: @ should be only added at the beginning or end of the string. You cannot have them as variable. For graphQl I would recommend writing everything within a json and then send the json.

Comment: @OblicionA thanks. The problem is that the text file has escape characters inside "\n" and then breaks when passing it as data and I wanted only to have a single field of data.

Comment: "\n" (and other special chars) never was a problem in json, just encode it properly